# Создание копии объекта

Tags: c#

Недавно я спрашивал про клонирование объекта, работая с такой структурой данных, как "Список". С методом клонирования разобрался. Теперь не получается сделать копию объекта, т.е. из главной программы создаётся новый объект (список), для которого вызывается метод копирования, в качестве параметра метода поступает имя другого объекта (другого списка), и как я понял, нужно, чтобы при изменении оригинала, менялся и копированный список. (язык C#)

Comment: ничего не понятно.

Comment: Покажите код, который успели написать, иначе не понятно, о каком объекте идет речь.

Comment: сначала был вопрос о клонировании, а потом удивление, что склонированные объекты не отражают изменений в исходных объектах

Comment: «не получается сделать копию объекта» — что означает _не получается_? Покажите ваш код и объясните желаемый эффект, а также расскажите, что происходит вместо этого.

Answer (score 0):

При копировании оператором `=` создаётся ссылка. Но при изменении нового обьекта меняется и исходный.

А после клонирования - исходный обьект не меняется.

Копировать объект можно через `new(старый объект)`

Comment: Это если у объекта есть такой конструктор. А если нету?

Comment: что тогда?.....

Comment: Если объект не предоставляет возможность для клонирования себя, то склонировать его, понятно, невозможно (законным путём).